# "/remote_debugger/vsdbg: not found" and "Failed to launch debug adapter" with docker-compose

Tags: docker, .net-core, docker-compose, visual-studio-2019

I'm getting this error whenever I try to run my project (with docker-compose) and cannot find any solution. I'm really hoping I've just been doing something dumb, so here goes...
I created a simple ASP.NET Core Web App (to test this out as I was having a problem on my "real" project.)

- .Net Core 3.1
- Visual Studio 16.11.3
- Docker Desktop ver 4.0.1 (Docker Engine: 20.10.8)

Scenarios below were tried on both WSL2 and Hyper-V.
Docker itself is running fine, I can use containers no problem.
**When I create the project with Docker support, I can run it fine (it creates the container, I can debug, etc)**

If I add a docker-compose setup, however, I get the following error popup when I try run my project (from VS)

[image: Failed to launch debug adapter]

The only thing I can see in the output window (debug) is this:
`The program '' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).`

To be clear, the build was successful, the container is running in docker, etc.
After much effort, I found a way to get more information by running the following in the VS Command window:
`DebugAdapterHost.Logging /On /OutputWindow`

I now can see some more detail (in Output - Debug Adapter Host Log) but don't know how to solve it.
The most relevant message (afaik) is
 **`1> ERROR: Debug adapter error output: /bin/sh: 1: /remote_debugger/vsdbg: not found`**

but here is the full output:
[image: Debug Adapter Host Log output]

So I'm pretty stumped. I've uninstalled and reinstalled docker countless times, tried every imaginable setting, ensured everything is running with admin privileges, and so on.

In case it helps, here is my debug output from the same run (note how it says vsdbg is found)
[image: build output]

Does anybody know what else I can try, or how to get more insight into this?

Comment: Note: this is very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66692612/failed-to-launch-debug-adapter-when-starting-docker-compose-in-visual-studio-20 but adds a significant extra piece of information that I think is important.