# Failed to launch debug adapter in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: .net, docker, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2022, docker-desktop

If I create an ASP Core MVC (Target Framework 5.0) with Docker support enabled and start it I get:

"*One or more errors occurred.
Failed to launch debug adapter. Additional information may
available in the output window.
The operation was cancelled.*"

This is the debug output:

[image]

Enabling DebugAdapterHost.Logging with

```
DebugAdapterHost.Logging /On /OutputWindow
```

Gives the following output:

```
1> DebugAdapterHost version: 16.9.50429.2 commit:ca34bde2a8dfef71e1d0b3bafd2804978bfbe6a9
 1> Starting 'docker' with arguments 'exec -i 7ce0da2e24860812b487ef583433deee7b411229b69c5631dc73027fd0864f1f /bin/sh -c "ID=.; if [ -e /etc/os-release ]; then . /etc/os-release; fi; if [ $ID = alpine ] && [ -e /remote_debugger/linux-musl-x64/vsdbg ]; then VSDBGPATH=/remote_debugger/linux-musl-x64; else VSDBGPATH=/remote_debugger; fi; $VSDBGPATH/vsdbg --interpreter=vscode"'
 1> [DebugAdapter] --> C (initialize-1): {"type":"request","command":"initialize","arguments":{"pathFormat":"path","clientID":"visualstudio","clientName":"Visual Studio","adapterID":"coreclr","locale":"en-US","linesStartAt1":true,"columnsStartAt1":true,"supportsVariableType":true,"supportsRunInTerminalRequest":true,"supportsMemoryReferences":true,"supportsProgressReporting":true,"SupportsMessageBox":true,"supportsHandshakeRequest":true,"supportsVsAdditionalBreakpointBinds":true,"supportsHitCountsChange":true,"supportsVsCustomMessages":true,"supportsVariableEnumerators":true},"seq":1}
 1> ERROR: Debug adapter error output: /bin/sh: 1: /remote_debugger/vsdbg: not found
 1> ERROR: Debug Adapter did not respond to initial requests.
 1> ERROR: Unexpected error

AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.

Aggregate exception: 
    DebugAdapterLaunchException: Failed to launch debug adapter.  Additional information may be available in the output window.

    Failure Location: UserCanceled
    Inner Exception: 
        OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
Inner Exception: 
    DebugAdapterLaunchException: Failed to launch debug adapter.  Additional information may be available in the output window.

Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.VSCodeDebuggerHost.Engine.Implementation.DebuggedProcess.<StartDebugAdapter>b__114_3(Exception ex)
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.VSCodeDebuggerHost.Utilities.TaskExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass11_0`1.<Catch>b__0(TException ex)
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.VSCodeDebuggerHost.Utilities.TaskExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass10_0`1.<Catch>b__0(AggregateException ex)

    Failure Location: UserCanceled
    Inner Exception: 
        OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.

 1> Debug adapter process exited.
 1> ERROR: One or more errors occurred.

Failed to launch debug adapter.  Additional information may be available in the output window.

The operation was canceled.
```

I have tried re-installing Docker Desktop and Visual Studio 2022. Windows 11 is fully updated.

I can build and run an Nginx image directly in Docker Desktop without errors so I think it has something to do with my Visual Studio 2022 install.

My setup:

*Docker Desktop 4.5.1*

*Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - 17.1.0*

*Windows 11 Home*

I also tried downgrading to:

*Docker Desktop 4.4.4*

*Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 (64-bit)*

But with exactly the same result.

Comment: Check your Windows Event Log for a more specific error message.

Comment: There are no errors in the Windows Event Log

Comment: I have now tried enabling log output from the DebugAdapterHost as described in a SO post quite similar to mine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69208007/remote-debugger-vsdbg-not-found-and-failed-to-launch-debug-adapter-with-do
I have added the output to the original post.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It turns out that "/remote_debugger/vsdbg" is indeed missing. It is expected to be found in "C:\Users\username\vsdbg\vs2017u5" on the host.

Deleting the whole directory ("C:\Users\username\vsdbg\vs2017u5") and then pressing F5 forces Visual Studio to re-create the directory and debugging now works.

Comment: Saved me after searching for a whole day, thanks for sharing this experience.

Answer (score 11):

For me this worked out:

1. clean and rebuild the solution.
2. Disable *script debugging* in Visual Studio, in the drop-down of green arrow, from where we run the project.

[image: Screenshot for step 2]

Comment: Sure it bypass the problem, but it does not solve it, since you no longer have script debugging

Answer (score 4):

I was getting the same error message box when trying to use python. For me, enabling native code debugging in the Debug Properties window fixed the issue. You can find Debug Properties under the Debug menu item.

I also had to download debugging symbols: Microsoft has documentation on how to do so [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/debugging-symbols-for-mixed-mode-c-cpp-python?view=vs-2022) but the quick run-down is to re-run the python installer, click modify, select both box checkboxes regarding debug symbols, and click Next/Install. Now everything works for me again.

[image: Enable native code debug checkbox]

Answer (score 2):

I got the exact same error  ***"The terminal process terminated with exit code: 4294967295"***

Tried  some of the ways

- Clean/Rebuild
- Restarted the Visual Studio.
- Deleting the directory (which was mentioned above)
- Changed the settings (tools -> options-> Debugging -> General ->enabling the "enable JavaScript debugging" and "multi-target JavaScript debugger"

I tried some of these links

[TheWindowsclub](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/wsl-process-exited-with-code-4294967295-in-windows-11)

[VSCodeIssues](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/93016)

Finally the problem solved by **restarting my PC**.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I did a Clean & Rebuild for the project. After this I closed an opened instance of the browser that I used previously to test.

After this I ran the project and a new instance of the browser opened for testing as usual.

Answer (score 1):

Like mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76385705/13624968) answer, closing all instances of Edge in the windows task manager solved the problem for me (having a Blazor WebAssembly application in VS 2022).

I had to filter for Edge, as there have been some "hidden" instances left in the background processes part of the task manager.